# Similarity between two nPn permutations of the same set.

Tags: permutations

Given two $nPn$ permutations of the same $n$-sized set, how can one find out the similarity between these permutations over the interval $[0, 1]$?

Comment: Is your idea that the sequence $\langle A, B, C, D, E\rangle$ should be considered similar to $\langle B, A, C, D, E\rangle$ and to $\langle E, A, B, C, D\rangle$, but less similar to $\langle C, E, D, A, B\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But how to quantify it? I search on the Internet, and found that one can think in terms of counting the number of "shift" operations it would take to convert one permutation into the other--something similar to Hamming distance.

Comment: If you have two permutations $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, you can find the "difference" between them as the permutation $\sigma_2\sigma_1^{-1}$, of which you can compute the inversion number or the disorder (same thing) as shown by the two existing answers.

Answer (score 3):

The "[Inversion number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29)" is a common way of measure permutation distance. There are other mesasures, (edit measures, as [Levenshtein distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206617/efficiently-determine-how-sorted-a-list-is-eg-levenshtein-distance)) that are actually more general (they measure arbitrary "strings" distance), but can be applied to permutations as special cases.

Answer (score 1):

See the section on computing the "disorder" of a permutation in these [PDF notes](http://www.coopersnotes.net/docs/groups/CHAP02%20Permutations.pdf) by Chris Cooper. It's Section 12.